# Как конвертировать pdf формат и обратно?

Tags: python, pdf

Я пытаюсь конвертировать pdf в другие форматы но толком нечего не получается
Я пытался использовать pypandoc

```
output = pypandoc.convert_file("test.docx", "pdf", outputfile="test.pdf")
output = pypandoc.convert("test.docx", 'pdf', outputfile="test.pdf", extra_args=['-V', 'geometry:margin=1.5cm', '--pdf-engine', '/usr/bin/xelatex'])
```

Мн пишет что мне нужно установить либо pdflatex либо xelatex
Я пытался установить pip install pdflatex и pip install xelatex
Но не помогло

Я пытался использовать pdf2docx

```
сonver = Converter("test.pdf")
сonver.convert("test.docx", start=0, end=None)
сonver.close()
```

Но в результате файл смещается кудато вправо в нижний угол

Comment: в какие форматы требуется конвертировать? текст, таблицы или смешанные данные?

Comment: @Violet смешанные данные.[image](https://warehouse-camo.ingress.cmh1.psfhosted.org/98291de103d6ed37d80b3686a38adf072039b469/68747470733a2f2f73312e617831782e636f6d2f323032302f30382f30342f6144727978312e706e67) [мой результат](https://i.ibb.co/X2FZWsp/sds.png)

Comment: нужен не pip install, а что-то типа sudo apt-get install

Comment: Никто не гарантирует обратимость преобразования pdf to doc